# Discrete Time Signals with Impulse Response

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, system, convolution, discrete-mathematics

I have this problem written by our professor in class and asked us to plot the output in Matlab.

[image: Matlab Problem]

Given the input x(t), I have created the function in Matlab. I also have converted it into digital samples since our class is focused on digital signal processing.

Given that T1 = 0.001 (which is 1000 Samples Frequency as Fs = 1/T1). I have have x(n) as a variable in Matlab. The next part on what to do has confused me, I also have plotted y(n) so now I have both x(n) and y(n).

From what I understand, y(n) = conv(xn,hn). Yet I already have y(n) and x(n). Does this mean I have to find h(n) and downsample it into 100 samples per frequency? Then plot x(t) and z(n)(which is h(n) as ive understood it(?)) from 0 to 2 seconds?

Or do I have to convolve x(n) with an impulse response which i dont have. Im very confused.

This is what i've written so far and im not even sure if the plots are correct.

```
close all; clear; clc;

% VARIABLES - Given that T=0.001, there are 1000 samples per frequency
T1 = 0.01;    % instead of 0.001 I used 0.01 since 1000 makes Matlab slow
Tf = 3;

% PLOTTING x(t)
t = 0:T1:Tf;
xt = ((mod(t,1))*0.5);
figure; plot(t,xt);

% DIGITAL SAMPLING x(t) - CREATING x(n)
nT = 0:T1:Tf;
xn = ((mod(nT,1))*0.5);
figure; stem(nT,xn);

% PLOTTING y(n)
y(1) = 0;
xn(1) = 0;

for n = 2:length(nT)
    y(n) = xn(n) - 2*xn(n-1) + y(n-1);
end

figure; stem(nT,y);

% DISCRETE TIME FUNCTION
% VARIABLES
T = 0.1;
Tfinal = 2;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code looks good. The big question is what the T=0.1 second within the DT system block is supposed to indicate. That seem unusual to me. If it means that the DT system will disregard any of the samples except those at [0, T, 2T, 3T ...] then setting T1 in your code to 0.1 seconds would be the way to go.

Comment: Since our lecture tackled downsampling, I think it means that the high sample signal input will be reduced from 1000 samples to 10 samples per frequency once it goes out of the system. The problem is I don’t know what to do once the signal goes in the system. I’ve done some research and figured that the x(n) should be convolved with h(n), however I don’t have h(n) but I have y(n) which confuses me on what to do.

Comment: You don't need the impulse response necessarily. You can also calculate the DT's system's output via the difference equation given by your lecturer (which you did). If you want to use the impulse response send a 1 (followed by 0s) into your difference equation and calculate the output of the DT system. Then you can do the convolution you described.